# How to handle ValueError while if int() is provided non-integer

Tags: python

Python reads function `input()` as string.
Before passing it to my function for division, variables are typecasted into int using `int()`.
If one variable is non-int (eg `"a"`) then how to catch it?

```
def divideNums(x,y):
    try:
        divResult = x/y
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please provide only Integers...")
    print (str(x) + " divided by " + str(y) + " equals " + str(divResult))

def main():
    firstVal = input("Enter First Number: ")
    secondVal = input("Enter Second Number: ")
    divideNums (int(firstVal), int(secondVal))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How to handle typecast of `firstVal` / `secondVal` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use isdigit function to check if the input values are integer or not

```
def main():

    firstVal = input("Enter First Number: ")
    secondVal = input("Enter Second Number: ")
    if firstVal.isdigit() and secondVal.isdigit():
        divideNums (int(firstVal), int(secondVal))
    else:
        print ("Please provide only Integers...")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right about using a `try/except ValueError` block, but in the wrong
place. The try block needs to be around where the variables are converted to
integers. Eg.

```
def main():
    firstVal = input("Enter First Number: ")
    secondVal = input("Enter Second Number: ")

    try:
        firstVal = int(firstVal)
        secondVal = int(secondVal)
    except ValueError:
        # print the error message and return early
        print("Please provide only Integers...")
        return

    divideNums (firstVal, secondVal)
```